# How to find the maximum number using Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I need to implement a method that compute the maximum number when three numbers are provided using Generics. I know how to do this using Comparable class but I need to use only numbers.

This is the code.

```
 public static <T extends Math>  T compareThreeValue(T x, T y, T z){ 
     T max=Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);
     return max; 
 }
```

I added this code to get idea of what I am trying.

Comment: Your bounded type doesn't make sense, you'll never be able to create an instance of `Math`.

Comment: What is the suitable bound type? Number class doesnt have max method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As All Primitive Wrappers for digits extends Number and they implement Comparable you could do

```
 public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> T max(T x, T y, T z) {
    return max(max(x, y), z);
}

public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> T max(T x, T y) {
    if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Also you could use

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(x,y,z))
```

as all numbers are `Comparable`. But you will have performance overhead of for creation of a new list.

Comment: the method max is undefined for the type Generic max(T, T) , I got this error.